# Yii framework - using checkbox filter

Tags: php, yii

I'm currently in the process in learning Yii framework.

Below is my code snippet. It is a list of categories, data coming from api :

```
        <div class="cbp-l-filters-button" style="width: 75%;">
            <?php foreach ($categories as $c): ?>
                <a class="cbp-filter-item <?php echo ($category == $c->id)?'cbp-filter-item cbp-filter-item-active':'' ?>" href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('//idea/frontend/explore', array('category'=>$c->id)) ?>">
                    <?php echo $c->title; ?>
                </a>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </div>
```

[image]

But now I want to change the categories into checkboxes like below:

[image]

but not sure how to go about this.. So far this is the code I tried but with no luck.

```
      <div class="row" style='float:left;;margin-left:5px'>
          <?php foreach ($categories as $c): ?>

              <?php echo '<span for="label" style="margin-bottom:5px;font-size: 0.9em;font-weight: bold;">Label</span><br />'; ?>
              <?php echo $form->checkBox($c,'title',array('value'=>1,'uncheckValue'=>0,'checked'=>($c->id=="")?true:$c->title),'style'=>'margin-top:7px;')); ?>
              <?php echo $form->error($c,'title'); ?>

              <?php endforeach ?>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a key to your loop and add that key to your attribute name.

```
 <?php foreach ($categories as $key => $c): ?>
      <?php echo $form->checkBox($c, '[' . $key . ']title';?>
 <?php endforeach ?>
```

See this article on working with tabular data.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.table